# How to configure the correct laser scan height in ROS Hydro for turtlebot?

Tags: laser, ros-hydro, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to adjust the laser scan height of kinect in ROS Hydro. The default configuration is for the kobuki base, however I'm using the turtlebot with create base. What should be the scan height for turtlebot?

The parameter is  **param name="scan_height" value="10"** in 3dsensor.launch file.

Please let me know the correct parameter value for scan_height to work with turtlebot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111796/how-to-configure-the-correct-laser-scan-height-in-ros-hydro-for-turtlebot?/) by [Brijendra Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6358/brijendra-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2013-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hydro now uses a new package to generate the fake laser scan - [depthimage_to_laserscane](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan), built by the folks from willow. It calculates directly from the raw depthimage and bypasses the point cloud processing.

Since this changed, it's very likely some behaviour is a little different to what you saw in electric. I've no experience with the electric fake laserscan package, but I suggest you should probably do some experimentation to understand the behaviour of the new package correctly. Some comments:

1. scan height should be independant of the base used - it's the number of scan lines used in the image.
2. We did notice an interesting behaviour once with it at 10. Setting it >1 causes it to scan within an arc out the front of the robot. This can actually create surprising obstacle detection situations resulting in (surprisingly) less robust behaviour. At a distance, it can trigger on obstacles that aren't directly in a horizontal line out the front of the sensor, and up close, it can completely miss these obstacles.

You might like to try setting it at 1 to see if this fixes any spurious behaviour you have. We haven't really done extensive testing to bulletproof the characteristic behaviour of this software yet - it's just a good starting point for people to experiment.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0